# PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, socialengine

In my error log I am getting a lot of PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: genderName in for all the variables under $UserData[''].  They are undefined because I am trying to define them using this array.  I was wondering what the best way is to define the variables so that I am not getting issues in the logs anymore.

```
            if (!$location) $location = "-";

                    $UserData = array();
                    $UserData['id'] = $UserInfo['user_id'];
                    $UserData['username'] = $UserInfo['username'];
                    $UserData['gender'] = $genderName;
                    $UserData['age'] = $age;
                    $UserData['photo'] = $photo;
                    $UserData['location'] = $location;
                    $UserData['description'] = $description;
                    $UserData['isAdminORModerator'] = $typeUser;
                    $UserData['profile'] = SITE."/".$UserInfo['username'];
                    $UserData['level'] = $level;
    }

    return  $UserData;
```

This is the full code for all who asked.

```
function commonData($uid)
{
    if ($uid)
    {
            $sql = "
                    SELECT a.user_id, a.email, a.username, a.displayname, a.level_id, a.photo_id
                    FROM engine4_users AS a
                    WHERE a.user_id = ".$uid;
    }

    $UserInfo = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));

    if ($UserInfo['user_id'])
    {

            if ($UserInfo['photo_id'] && $UserInfo['photo_id']!="NULL")
            {
                    $PPhoto = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_storage_files AS a WHERE a.file_id = ".$UserInfo['photo_id']));
                    $photo = SOFTLAYER.$PPhoto['storage_path'];
            }

            else $photo = NO_PHOTO;
    $queryMoreProfile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM engine4_user_fields_values AS a WHERE a.item_id = ".$UserInfo['user_id']);

    while ($moreProfile = @mysql_fetch_assoc($queryMoreProfile))
    {
            //birthday
            if ($moreProfile['field_id']==6)
            {
                    $age = getAge($moreProfile['value']);

            }
            //about
            if ($moreProfile['field_id']==13)
            {
                    $description = $moreProfile['value'];
            }

            //position
            if ($moreProfile['field_id']==17)
            {
                    $gender = $moreProfile['value'];
                    $gendersql = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_user_fields_options AS a WHERE a.option_id = ".$gender));
                    $genderName = $gendersql['label'];
            }

            //location
            if ($moreProfile['field_id']==24)
            {
                    $locationNumber = $moreProfile['value'];
                    $locationsql = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_user_fields_options AS a WHERE a.option_id = ".$locationNumber));
                    $location = $locationsql['label'];
            }
            //level
            if ($UserInfo['level_id']==1 or $UserInfo['level_id']==2)
            {
                    $typeUser = '<isAdmin>true</isAdmin>';
                    $level = 'admin';
            }
            else if ($UserInfo['level_id']==3)
            {
                    $level = 'moderator';
                    $typeUser = '<isModerator>true</isModerator>';
            }
            else if ($UserInfo['level_id']==9 or $UserInfo['level_id']==10 or $UserInfo['level_id']==11 or $UserInfo['level_id']==12 or $UserInfo['level_id']==13 or $UserInfo['level_id']==14)
            {
                    $level = 'premium';
                    $typeUser = '';
            }
            else if ($UserInfo['level_id']==8)
            {
                    $level = 'VIP';
                    $typeUser = '';
            }
            else
            {
                    $typeUser = '';
                    $level = 'guest';
            }

            if (!$location) $location = "-";

                    $UserData = array();
                    $UserData['id'] = $UserInfo['user_id'];
                    $UserData['username'] = $UserInfo['username'];
                    $UserData['gender'] = $genderName;
                    $UserData['age'] = $age;
                    $UserData['photo'] = $photo;
                    $UserData['location'] = $location;
                    $UserData['description'] = $description;
                    $UserData['isAdminORModerator'] = $typeUser;
                    $UserData['profile'] = SITE."/".$UserInfo['username'];
                    $UserData['level'] = $level;
    }

    return  $UserData;
```

}
}

Comment: So `$UserData['gender'] = $genderName;` isn't actually defining `$genderName` it is defining `$UserData['gender']`

Comment: in fairness I have left out a LOT of code.  But above this each of those variables is defined, and what I am doing is putting them into an array called $UserData - To be specific this is a common.handler file for a login script passing user profile information

Comment: @BossRyan If the runtime tells you that the variables have not yet been assigned to, then they haven't.  You will have to post all of the code between the snippet you have pasted and the initialization of these variables in order for us to diagnose any further.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that

```
$genderName
```

has never been assigned a value.

Use

```
if(isset($genderName))
{
    ...
```

To make sure that it exists.

You can also use the ternary operator

```
$genderName = isset($genderName) ? $genderName : false;
```

You have to do

```
$genderName = "something";
```

Because otherwise you can't do

```
$something = $genderName;
```

ARE you sure you're not trying to do this?

```
$genderName = $UserData['genderName'];
```

The variable insertion operation goes from right into the left variable.

Comment: to clarify the exact error is coming from undefined variable from 'id' 'username' 'gender' 'age' 'photo' etc etc

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. You never gave the varaibles a value.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, trying to do this? $genderName = $UserData['genderName '];

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like your snippet is from a function, based on the `return` keyword.  My guess is that you have assigned to the variables `$genderName` et al. from outside of the function.

If that is the case, then note that functions *do not* inherit global variables into their scope.  You have to explicitly request access to global variables by using [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  If you do not, then `$genderName` refers to a *function-scoped variable* that you presumably have not assigned to.

At the top of your function, for example, add this:

```
global $genderName, $age, ...;
```

You need to do this for each and every global variable that you intend to use in a function.  Note that this access is read-write; you can overwrite the value stored in global variables this way, so be careful.

Comment: all the variables on the right have been defined.  The error is coming from the left.

Comment: @BossRyan No, that's not what the notice indicates.  The left of an assignment cannot possibly be the source of the notice in this case. The text "Undefined variable: genderName" is crystal clear. Please show more code.

Comment: reviewing now... one moment ...

Comment: Are you sure you want to teach him to use global variables when he really should not? :P

Comment: @Jonast92 He is already using global variables.  Probably incorrectly, but without seeing the rest of his code it's not like I can make any reasonable suggestions regarding how he could restructure it anyway.

Comment: OH I was not going to use them.  While I get what he is saying and YES in testing it did fix my problem, it also helped me understand what to ask for.  The issue is $UserData['id'] has never been defined, and while creating the array I want the code above to be declaring all the variables for $UserData - forgive me I am not a code pro... just the guy who got stuck with this LOL

Comment: see my edit above to the initial question

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern in your code that will cause more than just notices.

This particular notice comes from the fact that the variable `$genderName` is only defined if the dataset you are working with contains a moreProfile-field-id of 17. Only then the query for getting the gender name from the database is performed and the variable comes to life. If not, the variable stays undefined, and you get the notice.

Actually, you try to return a complete record of a user. Which value do you return if the user hasn't saved his "genderName"? Empty string? NULL?

About this pattern: Your code has a tendency to not be very robust against failure:

```
if ($uid)
{
        $sql = "
                SELECT a.user_id, a.email, a.username, a.displayname, a.level_id, a.photo_id
                FROM engine4_users AS a
                WHERE a.user_id = ".$uid;
}

$UserInfo = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
```

`$uid` is the parameter to the function. I would expect it to be present, otherwise PHP complains. But there are plenty of values for `$uid` that are not "true", like 0, "", array(). What if `$uid` is seen to be "false"? Then `$sql` does not get defined. But it gets used for the query. And any error is suppressed, so you cannot know that your query failed.

And by the way: Your SQL is not secured against SQL injection attacks.

So the pattern is: You do stuff if things work well, but do not pay attention to what to do otherwise. Every `if` has an `else` part that is always there even if there is no code inside. You have to deal with this `else` part - even if you simply define the same variable there and assign a default value, like this:

```
        //position
        if ($moreProfile['field_id']==17)
        {
                $gender = $moreProfile['value'];
                $gendersql = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_user_fields_options AS a WHERE a.option_id = ".$gender));
                $genderName = $gendersql['label'];
        }
        else
        {
                $genderName = "I don't know";
        }
```